# Inductive strength & tracking requirement

Tags: philosophy-of-science, induction

An inductive inference is usually considered strong if its conclusion is probably true, given true premises. In [Tracking Track Records](https://philpapers.org/rec/LIPTTR-3), Peter Lipton (giving credit to Nozick) suggests that a strong inductive inference is such that the premises *track* the conclusion, meaning something like this, "had the conclusion been false, the evidence would have been different." (p. 186)

What's the difference?

Comment: Probabilistic conditional only imposes requirements on the possible worlds where the premise is true, adding the tracking condition *also* imposes requirements on the worlds where the conclusion is false. In general, high probability of a conditional does not say much about the probability of its contrapositive, see [contrapositive of probability](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/51745/250912). The tracking condition attempts to remedy that.

Answer (score 1):

Say that H = hypothesis, O = observation.  To compare the cases clearly, let's draw a Venn diagram of the possible outcomes:

```
╭H────╮
│A ╭──┼─O╮
│  │B │  │
╰──┼──╯C │
 D ╰─────╯
```

There's a box for H which intersects with the box for O.  I've labeled the four areas:  A = H \ O, C = O \ H, B = H ∩ O, D = (H ∪ O)ᶜ.

Notation:  \ is set difference; H \ O means "the parts of H that are not also in O."  ᶜ is set complement; (H ∪ O)ᶜ means "all the possible outcomes not in H and not in O."

If H is highly likely given O, this means that P(H|O)  =  P(B) / P(B ∪ C) is large (close to 1).

If Peter Lipton's condition, "had H been false, O would have been different," holds, this means that P(O|Hᶜ) is low (close to 0).  So this is saying that P(C) / P(C ∪ D) is small (close to 0).

Now, to see the difference, consider if the outer region D is very high probability (a very large region in the Venn diagram) which also means that H and O are, a priori, both unlikely.  In this case, Lipton's condition P(C) / P(C  ∪ D) is always going to be small, because the size of region D dominates the size of region C.

But increasing the size of region D has no effect on the condition that "the conclusion is probably true, given the premises"; P(H|O) is unchanged.

So, Lipton's condition as you've stated it would call an inductive inference strong, whenever both hypothesis and the observation are a priori unlikely, regardless of whether the hypothesis is related to the observation.  This is probably unintended behavior.  I would suggest that Lipton's condition is mistaken, or perhaps you've misinterpreted it.